# phpmyadmin mysql foreign key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

phpmyadmin version: 4.1.14

db engine: InnoDB

index already set:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_name` ADD INDEX( `user_id`);
```

My query:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_name` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `<db_name>`.`user`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

but im still got error:

```
#1215 - Impossible d'ajouter des contraintes d'index externe
```

In mysql documentation this error:

```
Erreur: 1215 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN)
```

whats wrong and what i must do for solve this?
Maybe i forgot something in phpmyadmin settings?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you literally trying to specify `<db_name>`.`user` as the name of the target table?

Comment: no, its just placeholder, query is like:
ALTER TABLE `post` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `alicelf_engine`.`user`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved, 
im add UNSIGNED to indexed column (for user_id )

```
`user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
```

I think, fields with relations must have same properties

Answer (score 0):

if in user table `id` primary key data type **INT** 
then in post table  `user_id` foreign key data type should be **INT** NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

> For me it was that I used **different types** in the rows of parent table and child table:

I used `Int` in `child_table_key_id` and `BigInt` in `id`