# Getting an error while SQL with Foreign KEY

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF Not EXISTS  `conversation` (
`c_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_one` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_two` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ip` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (user_one) REFERENCES users(user_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (user_two) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

This is my SQL query. I am getting this error

> 1215 - Impossible d'ajouter des contraintes d'index externe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260425/phpmyadmin-mysql-foreign-key

Comment: Can you help me creating this table cause the link you have provided has given the solution to add UNSIGNED but that's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually sorry for the inconvenience but I am very new to mysql, so I would like to share how I solved it. This query is absolutely right, My sql Foreign key used for connecting two tables. This helps making interface and it is also very safe. I was getting that error because of wrong table name. Suppose if you have given the reference- FOREIGN KEY (user_one) REFERENCES users(user_id), then 'user' is table name and user_id is row that exist in it. So it was my fault I am sorry for wrong question.